# Game trades. And downloads

Tags: xbox-360

I have a friend who wants this game that I have but he can't afford and he told me to download it on the Xbox market and give him the disc. If I do that will the disc still be useable even though I've downloaded it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The disc, and the downloadable version are two entirely separate games. You'll have to pay for the download obviously, so you're buying another version of it.